# How to graph grades based on an array of objects that contains all the info?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, date-arithmetic

I am trying to make something that graphs grades and I need to calculate points from an array of assignments.

OK, what I have is an array like this:

```
[{
    category: "assignment",
    date: 2/13/13,
    earned: 9,
    total: 10
}, {
    category: "assignment",
    date: 2/13/13,
    earned: 8.5,
    total: 10
}, {
    category: "test/quiz",
    date: 2/7/13,
    earned: 85,
    total: 100
}]
```

The dates are not necessarily in order and there can be multiple data points from the same day

And weights for the different categories:

```
[{
    "assignment": 40,
    "test/quiz": 60
}]
```

what I need is for a new array of arrays to be created with each object containing an overall weighted grade up to that point and the date. (i know [how weighting works](http://www.blacksdomain.com/files/Notes/Calculating_WA.php))

So the output of this would be:

```
[   //  [x, y]
    ["2/7/13", 87.5],
    ["2/13/13", 86.0]
]
```

Preferably in chronological order

where I get confused is how to programmatically combine multiple assignments from one day and combine them with the previous data and create a new point. This is just a simple example, usually there are many, many assignments from months of time

I have tried, but it contained what seemed to be way too many loops and was very confusing, so I scraped it. I was thinking there must be a better way to do this that is at leased a **little** simpler.

The data is pretty flexible, so it can be arranged in really any way. ex. the dates could be changed to timestamps if thats easier. or the object properties could be named something different.

I might be getting ahead of myself, but eventually I was going to store the data on the first run and then every other run just check for changes in the data and only calculate those new points

Comment: Well, can we see your attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/epoch/wxWJy/)? Not sure if I completely understood, but here is my go at it:

```
var scores = [{
    category: "assignment",
    date: '2/13/13',
    earned: 9,
    total: 10
}, {
    category: "assignment",
    date: '2/13/13',
    earned: 8.5,
    total: 10
}, {
    category: "test/quiz",
    date: '2/7/13',
    earned: 85,
    total: 100
}];

var weights = {
    "assignment": 40,
    "test/quiz": 60
};

function calculateCombined() {
    var dates = [], combined = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
        if (!dates[scores[i].date]) {
            dates[scores[i].date] = [];
        }

        dates[scores[i].date].push({
            weight: weights[scores[i].category] || 1,
            percentage: (scores[i].earned / scores[i].total) * 100
        });
    }

    for (var x in dates) {
        if (dates.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
            var tWeight = 0;
            dates[x].forEach(function(dVal) {
                tWeight += (dVal.weight / 100) * dVal.percentage
            });

            combined.push({
                date: x,
                wight: tWeight
            });
        }
    }

    return combined.sort(function(d, e) {
        return new Date(d.date) - new Date(e.date);
    });
}

console.log(calculateCombined());
```

Comment: Thanks SO much, i havent gotten a chance to test it with the rest of my code, but it looks fantastic!